# Adding Child nodes to a treeview at startup using a database

Tags: vb.net, treeview, parent, children

I have two different tables from a database i am using for populating a treeview in vb 2008, i have already successfuly displayed the parent nodes to the treeview. my problem is displaying the child nodes to each node. i have tried `treeview1.nodes("node text here").nodes.add("node text here")` but the problem is for me to find the node i am using an oledbdatareader. here is my current code...

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim mypath = "I:\Casegoods\Database\Expertpetrolia.mdb"
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider = microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;Data Source=" & mypath)
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim sql1 = "SELECT Due_Date, Date_id FROM Supply_Date ORDER BY [Due_Date]"

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Using conn

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql1, conn)
        conn.Open()

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr.HasRows Then
            Do While dr.Read()
                Dim parent As String = (dr.Item("Due_Date"))

                If DateDiff(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateInterval.Day, Today, (dr.Item("Due_Date"))) > -10 Then
                    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(parent)
                End If
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox("No Things found")
        End If

        dr.Close()

        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

im not sure if i need another oledbdatareader for reading the other table or another oledbcommand or what. i am having major coding block and i cant seem to come to a solution.

Comment: if "the other table" is related to this one in some way, you should be able to use a SQL JOIN to combine elements from both into your data set

Comment: both tables have a common column called "Date_Id" that have related numbers as per row. how would i use the sql join function, i have not seen that used in treeviews yet!

Comment: its a SQL thing not a Treeview thing: `Select A, B, C FROM tableA JOIN tableB ON tableA.Date_Id = tableB.Date_Id` there are different kinds of JOINS.  JOIN allows related data from 2 tables to appear in one dataset based on the column they share (called a Key).

Comment: so using this sql function in the cmd command will allow me to control both tables values?

Comment: "control" is not correct in this case, because a SELECT statement just reads data.  A JOIN (you probably want an INNER JOIN) combines data from 2 tables into one dataset (your dr)

Comment: i have this currently '"SELECT Date_Id, Due_Date FROM Supply_Date JOIN Total_Purchase ON Supply_Date.Date_Id = Total_Purchase.Date_Id"' and it gives me an error when i pass it throught he command saying there is a "Syntax error in FROM clause."

Comment: a) the IDs are not usually so interesting that they are part of the SELECT b) you didnt specify a unique column from Supply_Date that you are after c) you probably want a INNER JOIN to get rows only where there are matches for the ID in both tables.  see also: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: i have joined the two tables successfully, however instead of giving me the same nodes as before it is now giving me way more than i want. to explain, before i had each node as a unique date from "Due_Date" it is giving me repeating dates (one for every match as per "Date_Id").i would like the parent nodes to be each one unique date with no duplicates.

Comment: SQL is very powerful, and with great power comes the risk of goofing it up badly. Since this is an Access DB, you can build the query in the query builder and refine to what you want, then change the view to see the SQL; copy it and paste it into your code.  Its hard to say whats wrong without knowing the schema and the SQL you are using.

Comment: that is very true, given that i am relatively new to this level of coding it doesn't help my case. i do have code which i think should work but it doesnt and gives me an index out of range exception. im just not sure if what i want is possible at this point

Comment: another resource http://www.sourcecodester.com/Tutorials/sql/sql-tutorial.html  the visual query builder in Access is a good way to learn and make progress on a project as you do.

Comment: thank you very much you have been such a great help! ill take a look at that link and see if i cant figure it out.

Comment: wait. as to "repeating dates" - if there is one record in A with many records in B related to it, then it is working correctly.  The many Bs will repeat the related A data in each row - thats good.  First you need an ORDER BY clause to keep them together, then in code a Loop to add child nodes as long as the related A table value is the same.

Comment: http://s27.postimg.org/t6tvm5z2b/example2.png this is what my form currently looks like, the parent node list is very long because it is showing the same date repeatedly. what do you mean in that last sentence of your comment about coding the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are many records (>1) in Total_Purchase related to each Supply row, you will appear to get "repeating data" - the data from Supply will repeat because **it is** related to Total_Purchase and **is** part of the row/record as per your SQL INNER JOIN.

I **strongly** advise looking at the query in Access to understand what the dataset looks like.

The issue becomes adding child nodes in a loop until the Due_Date changes:

```
Dim parent As String = ""
Dim parentNode As TreeNode
If dr.HasRows Then
    Do While dr.Read()
        If (parent = (dr.Item("Due_Date"))) Then     ' same parent, add child
            ' add child node (presumably from tbl B data)
        Else
             parent = (dr.Item("Due_Date"))    ' set NEW parent value
             ' save parent node for adding child nodes above
             parentNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(parent)
        End If
    Loop
Else
```

Assuming the SQL is correct, you only add a new parent when it changes, otherwise add a child nodes for this parent until you detect a new Due_Date/parent.

Comment: would this be something i add in to my existing code or something that i replace my old code with?

Comment: its a mod of the existing `If dr.HasRows` block. It will need work, I focused on the parent detection and concepts because I know nothing about the schema, columns, data types etc. You also **dont** need the `If DateDiff` - that should be a WHERE clause in the SQL.  There is no need to pull the data in only to exclude some in code when you can exclude it from the source. DO paste your SQL into Access to see the nature of the dataset to better understand what you are working with.  And you WILL need a SQL ORDER BY clause for this to work right.

Comment: okay thank you, one final question. in the code you gave, is the text for the parent string supposed to be blank or do i have to put something in for that? and the datediff function i have because i want to only show date from ten days prior.

Comment: parent **is** set when it changes: `parent = (dr.Item("Due_Date"))` it starts as String.Empty for the first compare. you can do the date qualification in SQL using a WHERE clause so that those newer than 10days are not in the dataset at all.  something like "WHERE Due_Date < #05/04/2014#" (except use parameters)

Comment: okay yes i understand now. and the code is working for the parent nodes which is great! upon trying to add the child nodes it does give me an error though. `TreeView1.Nodes(parent).Nodes.Add(dr.Item("Purchse_order_number"))` that is what im using to add child nodes

Comment: "an error"? **always** helpful to know **which** error. in my code, I save the current parent node object, so you should just need to do something like `parentNode.Nodes.Add(dr.Item...` make sure the spelling is correct ("Purchse_order_number") and that column is in the query.

Comment: i have solved it using the method you just explained. turns out it didnt like the code i was using or something, anyways i have been able to get the parent nodes and the child nodes to come up in the form so i am happy, the only thing i need to do now is aesthetic things like changing the icon for the child nodes and trying to order the child nodes sequentially.